Google API, query user information
I'm working with the Google API, I got the token here
{
  access_token: 'ya...',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  id_token: 'eyJ...',
  expiry_date: 1...
}

How can I get the user information? I have used this endpoint but just able to get a few info
curl -i https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me -H "Authorization: Bearer ya..."
{
  "id": "11...",
  "email": "...",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "...",
  "given_name": "...",
  "family_name": "...",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg...",
  "locale": "en"
}

I would like to get more information such as creation time, and activities like use how active this account using (if available)

try the people api.

sorry, could you please give me this endpoint?

Let me just google that for you.  Here is the link to the documentation people api  ‍♀️
